# How to execute contract functions from Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

How can I call functions on a contract? I'm using remix to deploys contract but I don't know where to call the functions.

Comment: Why would you want to modify the contract after deploying it? What are you exactly trying to do? There's plenty of examples of deployed tokens/crowdsales. Just choose your favorite token and google it's github repo. Most of them have published the code on Github and also verified the code on Etherscan.

Comment: I actually did as just you said, I copied a source code of a token that is doing an ICO, I deployed it and when I send the ethereum to the owner adress I couldn't get my tokens, can you please send me a fine ICO repo, and I try that and let you know? And when I said modifiying it I actually meant how can I burn the last token left?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "using modifiers?".
I guess you are trying to ask how to call a function of the contract from remix.

If you open Remix for the first time it comes with a Ballot contract preloaded. Using that as example, on the right side select "Run" tab.

Click on the red "create" button to deploy the contract (this particular one requires you enter a uint8 with the number of proposals.).

Once you do that, the contract will be deployed and you will have access to calling it's exposed functions. That will appear on that same tab, below.

Red buttons are for transactions, blue ones are for calls.

[image]

Comment: Can I burn the last token with this way?

Comment: If the contract has that function exposed and when you call it the requirements are met, yes.

Comment: Thank you for whole answers! I'm looking for a launching ICO tutorial but I can't find a comprehensive one? Can you help me about that as well?

Answer (score 0):

What sort of modifications do you want to make once the contract is deployed? Typically you can't really modify an already deployed contract, otherwise people would not trust in them. The only way it is possible is if you include functions that will allow you to make changes, but this depends on the kind of changes you would like to make.

Comment: I guess I asked the wrong question, the thing I wanted to ask, how can I use modifiers in the contract? Like burning  the last token etc. I'm using remix for deploying it.